# Get total days from DatePicker java.util.Date Primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces

I'm trying to get the total days from the DatePicker java.util.Date Primefaces with the range selection mode, so that in the following inputtext it returns that number as an integer value, but it doesn't work even with Ajax call

the html code I have used is`

```
            <div class="form-group row"> 
                <p:outputLabel for="rango" value="Nombramiento" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"/>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <p:datePicker id="rango" inline="true"  size="" onblur="" numberOfMonths="2" selectionMode="range" value="#{ingresar.rango}" readonlyInput="true" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
                    <p:ajax  event="keyup" process="rango" update="dias"
                            listener="#{ingresar.rango}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <h:outputLabel value="Total de días" for="dias" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"/>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <h:inputText id="dias" required="true" requiredMessage="Campo Obligatorio"
                                 value="#{ingresar.rango.size}" class="form-control"/>
                    <h:message for="dias" class="text-danger"/>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [Showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-v8/ui/input/datepicker/datePickerJava8.xhtml) the `<p:ajax>` is inside the datepicker.

```
<p:datePicker id="rango" inline="true"  size="" 
    onblur="" numberOfMonths="2" selectionMode="range" 
    value="#{ingresar.rango}" readonlyInput="true" 
    pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">

    <p:ajax  event="keyup" update="dias" listener="#{ingresar.rango}"/>

</p:datePicker>
```

And if that does not work, maybe you want to try `event="dateSelect"` or `event="close"`

Comment: Yes I would try `event="dateSelect"` because keyup assumes the customer is typing and not using the mouse to select dates.